# How to debug indentation errors in python

Tags: python, debugging, indentation

I am trying to write my very first python script. This was working but then after some slight refactoring I have, apparently, broken the indentation. I can not determine what is the problem. The interpretor complains about the following method. Can someone point it out?

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    a = data.split(':')
    print a
    if len(a) > 1:
        command = a[0]
        content = a[1]

        msg = ""
        if command == "iam":
            self.name = content
            msg = self.name + " has joined"

        elif command == "msg":
            msg = self.name + ": " + content
            print msg
```

> The error reads: File "python_server.py", line 17
>       a = data.split(':')
>       ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the question is supposed to be about *knowing what indentation to use*, or about *using an editor to create* that indentation. But either of those has a better canonical duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start using a text editor that allows you to show indents, and you become consistent about using spaces instead of tabs, and you enforce that in your editor.

Comment: Yeah.. you're right. I opened the file in another editor and the indentation was different. Sublime Text was tricking me. Thanks.

Comment: 5 years later and Sublime Text still hasn't fixed this issue.

Comment: I use this settings in Sublime. Helps a lot.
    `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true, "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true, "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true`

Comment: In Sublime Text you can select all (CMD-A on Mac), and you can see the difference in indentation visually: the tabs will show as lines, and the spaces as dots. This is a quick way to identify any obvious issues.

Answer (score 53):

I encountered a similar problem using Sublime Text 2.

To solve, click on the "Tab Size" at the bottom of the editor, and choose "Convert Indentation to Tabs".

Answer (score 3):

There are a great number of things you can do here:

1. Use an editor that can show control characters (like `vi` with `set list`).
2. Use a hex dumper program like `od -xcb`.
3. Just delete the white space at the start of that line and re-insert it (may want to check the preceding line as well).

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the "Sublime Text 2" editor, then I found this answer helpful - it details how to turn on whitespace characters and also convert tabs to whitespaces

[sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Try Editra - www.editra.org

Your code looks fine, syntax seems fine...your text editor may be creating your errors. Review your file with Editra to see/review indentation levels.

Editra saved my sanity - I thought I had correct syntax when viewing my script in Text Editors including Notepad++ with python indent plugin. However, when I would run the script, it would throw off indentation errors every time. I finally opened the script up in Editra, and I could see the problem. Notepad++ and other text editors did not show correct indentations/tabs/spaces. Editra showed errors e.g. unexpected spaces, tabs - which I was able to correct.

Editra will auto-indent your script [and show errors -tabs, spaces -that may not show up in other text editors].

> If you have indent errors it will show up as blue underlined segment;
>
> > If you are writing script [adding/deleting lines] Editra will auto-indent the script.

**I would suggest opening your script and editing it in Editra.

Hope this helps!
Best of luck.
str8arrow