# Python Indentation Error

Tags: python

the following code is returning some strange indentation error inside a for statement. The console is pointing the error at a list.append() method. It should be a silly misstake onetime I am new at Python. heh

```
import os
import sys
import re
import glob

from Text import Text
from Word import Word
from FileCategory import FileCategory

class FileIO(object):

    def loadFile(self, filePath):

        newText = Text(os.path.basename(filePath))

        words=[]
        with open(filePath) as buff:
            content = buff.read().lower()
            re.sub("[^\w\s]", "", content)
            re.sub("[0-9]", "", content)
            words = content.Split(' ')

        for word in words:
            wordFound = next(auxWord for auxWord in newText.words if auxWord.textWord == word) 
            if wordFound is None:
                newWord = Word(word, 1)
                newText.words.append(newWord)
            else:
                wordFound.countInText+=1

        return newText

    def loadFilesFromDirectory(self, path):
        newCategory = FileCategory()
        files=[]
        os.chdir(path)
        for file in glob.glob("*.txt"): 
            files.append(file)

        for filePath in files:
            newFile = loadFile(filePath)
            if newFile is not None:
                newCategory.files.append(newFile)

        return newCategory
```

Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aprendizadMaq.py", line 6, in <module>
    from FileIO import FileIO
  File "/home/adolfosrs/Dropbox/7º Semestre/IA/T2/pyAprendizadMaq/FileIO.py", line 38
    files.append(file)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indentation Error in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that python doesn't like it when you mix tabs and spaces for indentation. Python relies on whitespace a LOT to figure out the levels of indentation, and hence scope.

As a result, when you have a line that has two <kbd>TAB</kbd>s on it, followed by a line with 4 <kbd>SPACE</kbd>s and a <kbd>TAB</kbd>, python proceeds to freak out and tell you that your indentation is off.

TL;DR: don't mix tabs and spaces. Stick to one or the other, and you should be fine.

Fun aside: if you really /really/ REALLY wanted to ignore this tip and try to mix the two, I believe <kbd>TAB</kbd>s are considered to be the equivalent of 8 <kbd>SPACE</kbd>s. So you could in theory do some indentation math there, to figure out how much to indent each line by, with a mix of the two. But this is HIGHLY unrecommended, and I'm probably going to burn in hell just for saying it

Comment: I knew it was a silly thing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open your file in a text editor that allows you to view whitespace.  Chances are you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Does Sublime has this feature?

Comment: @adolfosrs - Yes, it does. I have `"draw_white_space": "selection"` in my user preferences, so I can select text and see what kind of white space is present. Spaces are indicated by dots, and tabs by long dashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters