# Is it possible to visualize tabs and spaces on Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide

On Sublime Text you can visualize a tab (as a line), and space (as a dot) - as per [this StackOverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters).

Please is there something similar for the Cloud9 IDE?

e.g.

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to view invisible characters within the Cloud9 Editor, please visit the preferences panel (Cloud9 > Preferences), then click on User Settings, and then Code Editor (Ace) within Editors. Enable 'Show Invisible Characters' and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks dude! I prefer highlight trailing spaces like sublime style, but it's better than nothing!