# Python error I'm doing completely right but i got an error

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, syntax-error

I'm building a webcrawler in python. It is crawling an news site. but when i am getting this error:TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. it is in line 28 in my script. I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
    import requests
    from lxml import html
    import time
    from colorama import *

    def crawl():
        URL = "http://www.svt.se/nyheter/"
        host = "http://www.svt.se"
        blankHTML = requests.get(URL)
        tree = html.fromstring(blankHTML.text)
        Nyheter = tree.xpath('//span[@class="nyh_teaser__heading-title"]/text()')
        beskrivning = tree.xpath('//span[@class="nyh_teaser__text"]/text()')
        link = tree.xpath('//a[@class="nyh_teaser__link"]/@href')
        link_list = []
        newsnumber = 0
        numbersOfNews = 0
        for numb in range(1,10):
            print(Fore.GREEN + "Titel: " + Nyheter[newsnumber])
            print(Fore.YELLOW + "Beskrivning: " + beskrivning[newsnumber])
            print(link[newsnumber])
            link_list.append(link)
            newsnumber += 1
        choice1 = input("<News> ").lower()
        while True:
            if choicel == 1:
                URL = host + link_list[0]
                blankHTMLS = requests.get(URL)
                treek = html.fromstring(blankHTMLS.text)
                wholeNew = treek.xpath('//div[@class="nyh_article__body]/p/text()')
                print(wholeNew)






    crawl()
```

Comment: Recommend converting all tabs ('\t') to four spaces ('    ').

Comment: I don't really understand how you mean could you try to explain it another way?

Comment: You should set your  editor to use 4 spaces instead of tabs. Most of them have a setting to do this. Which one do you use?

Comment: i use sublime text

Comment: Try viewing your white spaces and tabs as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters).

Answer (score 0):

Your error would be caused by mixing tabs and spaces for your indentation. They were lost when you pasted your code example here so I am unable to reproduce the issue. You can use either but [you can't mix them in the same code block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034538/1519290). You can try opening your python file with something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and enabling `View > Show Symbol > Show White Spaces and TAB`.

I also noticed some other errors that may trip you up. You have an infinite loop so your program will never finish. Also you create a variable called `choice1` but later refer to it as `choicel` which will cause an error.

Comment: Ok i'll i i will download notepad ++

Comment: You don't have to. You can [view TAB and Space characters in Sublime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters) as well.

Comment: I'm linux i can't download

Comment: see my previous comment.

Comment: how? by the way i'm new to stackowerflow is there something to accept answers or something

Comment: If you refresh the page, you will be able to see all the comments. Welcome to SO.