# newbie: idled python def

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm feeling a rabbit posting this question, but I don't continue because this:
What's is wrong with this stretch of my code:

When I put something after the "if" I receive:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

For example, if I put "cont =3" after the "if" and before "post = form2.save(commit=False)" I receive:

> File
>   "/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/app/views.py",
>   line 59
>       post = form2.save(commit=False)
>                                     ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

If I put the same expression but before of "post = form2.save(commit=False)" I receive:

> File
>   "/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/app/views.py",
>   line 59
>       cont = 3
>              ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

the code:

```
def evaluation(request):
    # form2 initialization
    list_evaluation = Evaluation.objects.all()
    form2 = EvalForm()
    cont = 0

    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid() == True:
            cont = 3
            post = form2.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('canditate_list')
    else:
        form2 = EvalForm()
    return render(request, 'app/evaluation.html', {'criterions': form2,})
```

[EDIT]:
Guys, I don't indented wrong because I just press "Enter" before I type "True:",There's no way I could have mistaken it if the editor did this automatically

[EDIT2]:
I NEVER use space to indent my codes precisely avoid this problems, I ALWAYS use "tab" and just "tab"

Comment: Make sure you always use the same kind of indenting. Putting enough spaces to match the width of a tab in your editor is not the same and will cause hard to track problems.

Comment: But I using the same kind of indenting here, right?I just put the bar on the "if" side and hit enter, what did I do wrong?

Comment: That last exception indicates you are using tabs some places and spaces other places. You should probably just always use 4 spaces to indent a line as suggested by PEP8.

Comment: I just put the bar on the "if" side and hit enter, what did I do wrong? And I always use "tab" for to don't have problems...

Comment: If you really do always use tab, I don't know what the problem might be. That last exception clearly says there are tabs and spaces mixed.

Comment: I see mixed tabs and spaces in your post. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor, and you'll definitely see mixed tabs and spaces. If your editor doesn't have a "show whitespace" feature, get a better editor.

Comment: Also, what the heck is "idled" supposed to mean here?

Comment: is identation (google translate sorry) Identation

Comment: You can see spaces, but I DONT USE SPACE to ident my codes, I always use just the "tab" exactly for avoid this problems...

Comment: As I said above: I just put the mark bar ( | ) aside of the line of "if" and press enter, the editor idented automatically

Comment: Well, you have both spaces and tabs. Mostly spaces, actually. If you don't know how they got there, figure it out.

Comment: I see you've started angrily denying the problem. You'll solve your bugs much faster once you get out of that habit.

Comment: I dont angrily dude, sorry if I was thick or something, but, I NEVER use space, just to avoid this kind of problem, I have the "tab" as my personal programming standard, you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this happens because sometimes tabs != spaces. This also depends on type of editor a person is using.

A tab could be a different number of columns depending on your environment, but a space is always one column.

Spaces are the actual lowest-common denominator in punctuation.Many decent text editor has a "replace tabs with spaces" and this makes easier for programmers to just hit TAB key and get the desired indentation.

If you ever face such an error, try using spaces, because you can't go wrong with spaces, you might go wrong with tabs.

Latest editors like PyCharm follows PEP-8 and according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), it's recommended to use spaces only for indentation in Python programs.

Comment: I understanding, thanks for the tip, but I use sublime text, you know if this editor have tool to check this?

Comment: @DouglasdaSilva: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters

Comment: HELL YEAH, all done now, thank you very much for your attention and help,brother!

Comment: @DouglasdaSilva I'm glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about indentation!  Python determines what where the code is based on its indentation (rather than `{}` like most other languages).

Here's an example, this is valid code:

```
if 1 == 1:
    print('If passed!')
```

Once the `if` statement determines that `1 == 1` is `True` it looks for the indentation on the next line and runs it!

Here's another example, this is invalid code:

```
if 1 == 1:
print('If passed!')
```

Once the `if` statement determines that `1 == 1` is `True` it looks for the indentation on the next line, however, it doesn't find the indentation, so it doesn't know what to do, so it throws an `IndentationError`

In your code, you have this, and it works!

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
```

My guess is that when you add the `cont = 3` you add it like this

```
if request.method == "POST":
cont = 3
    form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)
```

So when python gets passed the `if` statement it looks for the next indentation, but there is none, so it throws an `IndentationError`.

I hope this helps you understand what's going on!

Comment: Well friend, I understanding and know all your tell me, but I idled right, take a look in my code

Comment: Hum, it seems like it's a tabs vs spaces problem or something in that case.  Could you edit your question to include the code that causes the error?

Comment: My guess would be there is some off character there.  Try deleting the entire line and copying the `        form2 = EvalForm(request.POST)` line above and see if that works.