# How to deal with u\200b in sublime text?

Tags: css, file, google-chrome-devtools, sublimetext3

[image: css error]

I got this strange red dot with the text "\u200b" that appear when i check the google chrome developper tools.
When i check my original css file there's nothing strange, i discovered that it was a [**Zero width space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).
So i try to find how to [delete it](http://rdzhou.github.io/2017/07/31/How-to-Remove-u200b/) on sublime text but i got this message below 
[image: sublime text error]

Does someone know how to handle this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: See if the character shows up in Sublime if you enable `"draw_white_space": "all"` in Preferences. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters

Comment: You need to click the `[.*]` button (next to `[Aa]`) to enable RegEx mode, then it will work fine.

Comment: thanks guys, i did the advice of Alex K. , it worked perfectly !