# Removing annoying whitespace dots

Tags: sublimetext3

I have some package that's adding indent guides in the form of dots for every whitespace, and I find it really annoying. How can I figure out what package is doing this, or override this thing (I have many packages in sublime text)?

It seems to happen only in my python files without text highlighting, but all files when I highlight text.

[image: Annoying dots]

I've tried looking through all package settings within **Preferences > Package Settings**.

Comment: Found this after a while as I'm new to the settings within Sublime Text. Turned out to be an option set in the Anaconda package specifically for python. Fixed: 
`"draw_white_space": "none"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 - View whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153998/sublime-text-2-view-whitespace-characters)

Comment: @AlexP Write up an answer to your question with the solution.